# Is there any way to pause ‘mousemove’ event until task complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Is there any way to pause `mousemove` event until task complete?

```
$( document ).bind( 'mousemove', function ( e )
{
    // mousemove: please wait and stop moving
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove');

    // I am the task
    $.ajax( {
        url: '/getData',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function ( result ){}
    } )
    .done(function()
    {
        // I am done, start moving...
        document.addEventListener('mousemove');
    });
} );
```

What I want:

- mousemove event fired and stopped as
  soon as it is fired.
- Function inside it executes.
- When function done executing,
  mousemove event starts again firing
- What this does is pause the mouse
  move event until task is done or
  fails.

Comment: `.bind()` is a deprecated function. Try to use `.on()` (assuming you're using jQuery 1.7+)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, why do you mix raw DOM/event access with jQuery? Don't do that.

To achieve what you want simple make your function a non-anonymous one and use `$(document).one('mousemove', yourFunction);` to bind it - both somewhere outside and in your `done()` function.

```
function handleMouseMove(e)
{
    // I am the task
    $.ajax({
        url: '/getData',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function ( result ){}
    })
    .done(function() {
        $(document).one('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    });
}

$(document).one('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your task time is small.
You can use a bool flag to keep a lock on mousemove functionality.
This will call the function on mousemove though, but return without doing anything
until you release the lock.

```
var moveFlag = true;

$( document ).bind( 'mousemove', function ( e )
{
    if(moveFlag == false)
         return;

    moveFlag = false;

    // I am the task
    $.ajax( {
        url: '/getData',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function ( result ){}
    } )
    .done(function()
    {
        // I am done, start moving...
        moveFlag = true;
    });
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag to disable/enable it like this:

```
$(document).data('enableMyMouseMove',true).bind('mousemove',function (e) {

    if($(document).data('enableMyMouseMove')) {
      $(document).data('enableMyMouseMove',false);
      $.ajax( {
        url: '/getData',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (result) {},
        complete: function (){ $(document).data('enableMyMouseMove',true); }
      });
    }
});
```

Notice that I have moved your 'done' function into the `complete` eventHandler on the ajax call, since imo, that is cleaner, but you can keep the done function if your wish, the logic is the same.

Try to avoid binding/unbinding event handlers all the time, since it is a very easy way to create memleaks unless you know what you are doing, especially in ie.

The reason for this is that ie has separate garbage collection for js and DOM objects, and if there is a cyclic reference between the two, garbage collection will not occur. Creating cyclic dependencies between js and DOM happens very easily when you bind eventHandlers